# c# custom messageBox show

Tags: c#, messagebox

I need to show up custom messageBox and close it when operation is done.
Problem is messageBox appear normal but without added label wich shows message , i can see only white space...After job is done , messageBox closing work normal.

here is code

```
public void resetirajSve() {

        MyMessageBox poruka = new MyMessageBox();

        poruka.Show();
        analizaPodataka();
        glProstor.Rows.Clear();
        poruka.Close();
}
```

I tried using poruka.ShowDialog() but then code wont to continue executing.. with showDialog  method label apper normal...

```
public partial class MyMessageBox : Form
{
    public MyMessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: it seems you have custom class MyMessageBox? where is that code

Comment: updated question :)

Comment: you are  talking about MessageBox but your code intends to use Form. I thin you dont know diff. b/w MessageBox and Form

Comment: how do you update the label ? did you try Label.Update ?

Comment: label message is defined in MyMessageBox Design... it's always same.. i tried label.Update... same thing

Answer (score 0):

Some pointers:

1.It seems your custom MessageBox actually inherits a Form. The default MessageBox is rather versatile - [see some examples](http://www.dotnetperls.com/messagebox-show), so there's no need to reinvent the wheel. Focus on more important things.

2.Using ShowDialog() will block all actions from executing on the Form until the newly opened form (you call it MyMessageBox, but it's actually a Form).

3.You could just add a ProgressBar control to display the task's progress and use the wait cursor until it is finished.

4.To avoid the program window becoming unresponsive until the method has finished executing (it can be an issue if it takes a long time), you might want to take a look at asynchronous programming. [Here's an example.](https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/10/simple-async-await-example-for-asynchronous-programming/)